# how to do flow direction raster cell by using numpy in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have found this code in the here.

Can someone explain what does this means:

```
(array[1+i: N-1+i,1+j: N-1+j]-array[1: N-1,1: N-1])
```

Comment: The full picture is missing. I am assuming that you have a numpy array named array, which is at least 2d. The operation is substracting a slice of the array from another. To know more about indexing and slicing you can check [here](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: @FBruzzesi i have my array with shape 6,6 with my N=6, if you can see above code, they were call the array with the shape 4,4. i have try on changing the code to 6,6 but python tell me the operands was 6,5. why?